# How to use "Join Clip" in iMovie'09?

Tags: dvd, video-editing, authoring, imovie

I have been using iMovie'09 for two days only. I need to edit some videos and make a DVD for a friend.

It happens to me that I want to join two clips together to form one continuous clip, so when I export the video to iDVD, they won't be treat as two different chapters.

The most obvious way to do so is to choose **Edit->Join Clip**, but that menu item was always gray out when I chose two adjacent clips. I tried to highlight two/three adjacent clips, two apart clips etc, but it is still grayed out.

I googled for a while but it seems no one knows, anyone knows how to use the **"Join Clip"**?

Comment: I just find it out by myself.

It turns out if you have just split a clip into two, then you can "Join Clip" together by highlight the two just split clips...

I wish this "Join Clip" feature is about joining two unrelated clips, but it turns out to be quite useless, since you can always undo the splitting.

Question closed.

Comment: i found out that for some reason you can only join clips that do not have sound attached to them. I could not join clips that still had their sound attached or even clips in which the audio had been split, but was still pinned to the video. Only clips that had no sound either still attached or pinned to them could be joined. I dont really understand why it works like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just dragging them both onto the timeline with no gap in between? Then you can just export that and burn it using iDVD. I cannot imagine why that would not work

Comment: yeah, but I wanted to join two clips together to show as one in iMovie.

Comment: "Join clip" is a quite meaningless feature in iMovie. Anyway putting to adjacent clips together is literally "Join Clip".

Comment: I think this is a very poor answer because it does not address the actual question of 'how to join two clips', instead it answers the question 'how to avoid joining two clips'.

Answer (score 2):

i had two clips, selected the first, hit "join clip" and it worked fine. you don't need to have both clips selected...

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of options; the below is the best out of them all. To join two clips to make a single clip:

1. Drag your clips which are present in your events to "Project Library" area in iMovie.
2. In the menu toolbar, Click on Share -> Export using QuickTimePlayer
3. Choose the destination folder (Ex: Desktop)

Done. Your new clip (single clip) is ready!

Answer (score 1):

Go to SHARE/EXPORT and the clips will become one continuous movie.